# Extract multiple values using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

So, I am trying to extract multiple values from a string using sed that are separated by ",".

```
Working Eg:

Input :
    echo "abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4" | sed -E 's/(^([a-z]{3}-[a-z]{1,5}-[a-z]{1,5}-[a-z]{1,15})).*/\1/'

Output: 
     abc-de-aa-zzzz
```

Need help with the below expression:

```
Not Working Eg:

Input:
    echo "abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4,abc-de-aa-kkkk-1.2.5-4" | sed -E 's/(^([a-z]{3}-[a-z]{1,5}-[a-z]{1,5}-[a-z]{1,15})).*/\1/'

 Current output:
      abc-de-aa-zzzz

 Correct output:
      abc-de-aa-zzzz,abc-de-aa-kkkk

 This one works as well:
      abc-de-aa-zzzz
      abc-de-aa-kkkk
```

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Thanks, updated the question. That still doesn't fix my current issue though.

Comment: am I right in guessing that from each column which are separated by `,`  you want to extract string around the first three `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to delete only string not needed, in this case deletion pattern is `-` followed by 3 set of digits with `.` as delimiter and then a final sequence of digits

```
$ echo "abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4,abc-de-aa-kkkk-1.2.5-4" | sed -E 's/-([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+-[0-9]+//g'
abc-de-aa-zzzz,abc-de-aa-kkkk
```

**Alternate solutions:** - extract what is required

Using `grep` and `pcre`

```
$ echo "abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4,abc-de-aa-kkkk-1.2.5-4" | grep -oP '(^|,)\K([^-]+\-){3}[^-]+'
abc-de-aa-zzzz
abc-de-aa-kkkk
```

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ echo "abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4,abc-de-aa-kkkk-1.2.5-4" | sed 's/,/\n/' | sed -E 's/^(([^-]+\-){3}[^-]+).*/\1/'
abc-de-aa-zzzz
abc-de-aa-kkkk
```

In case you need to combine the output as single line delimited by `,`

```
$ echo "abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4,abc-de-aa-kkkk-1.2.5-4" | grep -oP '(^|,)\K([^-]+\-){3}[^-]+' | paste -s -d,
abc-de-aa-zzzz,abc-de-aa-kkkk
```

Comment: the sed expression is not returning both the strings in new lines, also is it possible to do have both the strings separated by ","

Comment: I copy pasted the solution after testing on GNU sed, what is your sed version? and for extracted output in same line separated by `,` use `paste -s -d,`

Comment: The one on my macbook, not sure how can I find what version of sed is running as sed -V doesnt work.

Comment: use `sed --version` and check in `man sed` if extended regex is an option

Comment: can you check if `echo "abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4,abc-de-aa-kkkk-1.2.5-4" | sed -E 's/-([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+-[0-9]+//g'` this works?

Comment: @Jason: Am not sure why would like to make your solution the most least portable by trying out options specific to a particular platform when you can do a generic solution applicable in all environments. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

Sample input:

```
echo $x
abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4,abc-de-aa-kkkk-1.2.5-4
```

`awk` only  solution:

```
 echo $x  |awk  'BEGIN{RS=",";FS=OFS="-"}{NF=4}1'
 abc-de-aa-zzzz
 abc-de-aa-kkkk
```

OR this, if you want output to be comma separated. (One extra comma at the end)

```
echo $x  |awk  'BEGIN{ORS=RS=",";FS=OFS="-"}{NF=4}1'
abc-de-aa-zzzz,abc-de-aa-kkkk,
```

dirty solution using `tr` and `awk`:

```
echo $x |tr ',' '\n' |awk -F'-' -v OFS='-' '{NF=4}1'
abc-de-aa-zzzz
abc-de-aa-kkkk
```

Comment: other than possibly doing it all using awk alone, I think this is rather neat solution which cleanly extracts based on field separators

Answer (score 1):

It can be done pure Bash [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) techniques but it involves multi-levels of extraction (two) though without using any third partly Linux tools like `awk` or `sed`. You can run them directly on the command line.

```
# Read the input string into a bash array with a comma delimiter
$ IFS="," read -ra inputString <<< "abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4,abc-de-aa-kkkk-1.2.5-4"

# For each of the individual strings, extract the sub-string from the end
# with de-limiter set as '-'
$ for eachString in "${inputString[@]}"; do tempString="${eachString%-*}"; \
       tempString="${tempString%-*}"; printf "%s\n" "$tempString"; done
abc-de-aa-zzzz
abc-de-aa-kkkk
$
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do it using sed though ?

Comment: @Jason: When you can do it in native `bash` shell, you don't need any other tools, improves performance and portability in most cases.

Comment: good one using parameter expansion alone :) can use `for eachString in "${inputString[@]}"; do echo "${eachString%-*-*}"; done` as well

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{while(++i<=NF){sub(/-[0-9].*/,"",$i);print $i}}'
```

Sample:

```
echo "abc-de-aa-zzzz-1.2.3-4,abc-de-aa-kkkk-1.2.5-4" | awk -F, '{while(++i<=NF){sub(/-[0-9].*/,"",$i);print $i}}'
abc-de-aa-zzzz
abc-de-aa-kkkk
```